# How to define Jackson databinding dependency in build.sbt?

Tags: java, scala, jackson, sbt

I want to use the [Jackson databinding API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding) in a Scala/Java project, that is managed by sbt. The Jackson dependency should be as slim as possible, no Scala stuff etc.

How do I depend on Jackson 2.4 from `build.sbt`?

Jackson will be used like this from my code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(dst, myBean);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SBT read up on [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html), in there it states you can add dependencies with:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision
```

The dependencies come out of a usually remote repository which seems to include Maven Central, so [search for what you need there](http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=com.fasterxml+jackson). Then you should end up with something like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.0"
```

( Assuming this is the actual dependency, 2.4 is referenced from the question, personally I use the codehaus builds )